Pipeline is not getting updated/removed from Compliance Governance in Azure DevOps
We are tracking Compliance governance in dev.azure.com. One of our pipelines showed up in compliance governance stating that one of the package either needs to be updated or removed. We have already deleted the pipeline and went to Compliance Governance and had Sync Now option but it is not getting updated the Pipeline is still showing with Compliance Governance issue and also the package is still showing the issue with Critical Level: High.
I need help understanding:

How to remove the pipeline from Compliance Governance which is already deleted from the pipelines
How to remove the alert that is showing for a particular package associated with the pipeline.



What do you mean pipeline is showing Compliance Governance issue? Are you using pipelines to scan the dependencies referenced by your code? Please specify which pipeline task has reported the issue, share your pipeline definition and issue messages and screenshots if applicable to help understand how the issue is reproduced.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT Thank you for the reply. We have .NET core and react application developed. When we deploy our code, there is component governance task that scans our packages. If the CG finds any issues with the package, it shows in the CG tab in dev.azure.com
I have attached screenshot in the question. Thank you

So the issues are with the app code in your repo that is using incompliant packages? Do your developers have a plan to resolve those issue dependencies? What is your actual expectation in this post, to resolve the dependencies issue or just stop the CG scan? By the way, which task your pipeline ran for CG scan? Was it an extension task in  Marketplace?

If the CG scans reported vulnerabilities, you may probably search for existing resolution to update the packages referenced in your code.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT Our developers resolved the issue but unfortunately, we deleted the pipeline which was discovering these alerts. As we have deleted the pipeline, we also want to get rid of those alerts that were discovered by that particular pipeline.
It was dotnet build task that discovered the issues

Since this is regarding a private extension, we may leverage the internal resources for further investigation.

Based on our discussions, it appears the issue arises from duplicate alerts in the CG pipeline filter when the job name of the same pipeline has been modified.
Please verify whether these alerts are resolved when the detected vulnerabilities are addressed. If the alerts persist under the filter with the old agent job name after remediation, consider modifying your pipeline definition to temporarily use the old job name and rerun the pipeline to determine if this resolves the existing alerts.
As this issue involves a private extension functioning as an internal tool, it is also advisable to contact the extension maintainers for further investigation and support.
